# How to python Scrape text in span class

Tags: python

So I'm making a bitcoin checker practice and I'm having trouble scraping data because the data I want is in a span class and I don't know how to retrieve the data.

so here is the line that I got from inspect:

```
 <span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs"> 11,511.31 USD </span>
```

I want to scrape the "11,511.31" number. How do I do this? 
I tried so many different things and I honestly have no clue what to do anymore.

here is the URL:[link](https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD)

Im scraping the current USD price (right next to "BTC/USD")

EDIT: Guys a lot of the examples you gave me is where i input the data. Thats not useful because i want to refresh the page every 30 seconds so I need the program to find the span class and extract the data and print it'

EDIT:current code. need to get programm to get "html" part by itself

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD'
#program need to retrieve this by itself 
html = """<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs">11,560.00 USD</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
spans=soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs'})
for span in spans:
    print(span.text.replace('USD','').strip())
```

Comment: *... tried so many different things...*. Share how you tried "those things"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to search for the right tag and class -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """
<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs"> 11,511.31 USD </span>
"""

html = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

spans = html.find_all('span', {'class': 'MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs'})
for span in spans:
    print(span.text.replace('USD', '').strip())
```

Searching for all `<span>` tags and then filtering them by `class` attribute, which in you case has a value of `MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs`. Once the filter is done just loop through the spans and using the `.text` attribute you can retrieve the text, then just replace the 'USD'.

**UPDATE**

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/trades'
res = requests.get(url)
json_res = json.loads(res.text)
print(json_res[0]['price'])
```

No need to understand the HTML. The data in that HTML tag is getting populated from an API call which has a JSON response. You can call that API directly. This will keep your data current.

Comment: I tried you way and it works but only if i manually enter:html_text = """
<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs"> 11,511.31 USD </span>
"". However as this element is always updating, i need the prgram to featch this. do u know how to do this?

Comment: you fetch it through `requests` module

Comment: how exactly do i do this

Comment: The underlying data is coming from an API.

Comment: i posted my current code up there. how do i get the program to retrieve the """<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs">11,560.00 USD</span>"""

Comment: thank you so much! Although i have no clue what each line of the code does. im guessing that i should learn to use the request library? Only started learning web scraping so dont really know much

Answer (score 0):

you can use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

For beautifulsoup, the code like as following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs"> 11,511.31 USD </span>""", "lxml")

print(soup.string)
```

The lxml is more quickly

```
from lxml import etree

span = etree.HTML("""<span class="MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs"> 11,511.31 USD </span>""")

for i in span.xpath("//span/text()"):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a real browser like Selenium-Firefox. I tried to use Selenium-PhantomJS, but I failed...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = 'https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')

driver.get(url)
sleep(10) # Sleep 10 seconds while waiting for the page to load...

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") 
spans=soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs'})
for span in spans:
    print(span.text.replace('USD','').strip())

driver.close()
```

Output:

```
11,493.00
+
3.06 %
13,432 BTC
[Finished in 15.0s]
```